# What closed the modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a twitter bootsrap modal. It contains the buttons "Save", "Cancel" and the arrow for closing. How do handle the case (and recognize it) when the modal is closed by the arrow and when by a button?

```
  $("#myModal).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    // ??? Arrow or button is the initiator
  });
```

Comment: Remove the bootstrap data toggles on those buttons and then apply events to them to differentiate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook into the button/icon clicks yourself and dismiss the modal from javascript. Here is an example:

```
$(function () {
    var myModal = $("#myModal");
    $("#btnShow").on("click", function () {
        myModal.modal("show");
    });

    myModal.find(".closeIcon").on("click", function () {
        console.log("Close Icon clicked.");
        myModal.trigger("myModal.dismiss.closeIcon");
        myModal.modal("hide");
    }).end().find(".closeButton").on("click", function () {
        console.log("Close Button clicked.");
        myModal.trigger("myModal.dismiss.closeButton");
        myModal.modal("hide");        
    }).end().find(".saveButton").on("click", function () {
        console.log("Save Button clicked.");
        myModal.trigger("myModal.dismiss.saveButton");
        myModal.modal("hide");        
    });

    myModal.on("myModal.dismiss.closeIcon", function () {
        console.log("Close Icon Handler called.");
    }).on("myModal.dismiss.closeButton", function () {
        console.log("Close Button Handler called.");
    }).on("myModal.dismiss.saveButton", function () {
        console.log("Save Button Handler called.");
    });
});
```

Basic Modal HTML (with classes for closeIcon, closeButton, and saveButton added to be able to dispatch the events).

```
<button id="btnShow">Show Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close closeIcon" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default closeButton" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary saveButton">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KvZND/).

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to track event while closing the modal with `data-toggles` like `data-dismiss="modal"`.

Try to use the events on each of them to get resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted your answer because I read what you wrote to mean: you can't use the data-dismiss and still be able to use a click event handler.  If you edit your answer I can upvote it again -- currently, voting is locked for me now that I downvoted.